# Where did I go wrong in my loops in my code?

Tags: c, cs50

I was trying to program a Mario half pyramid in C but my code is not doing anything.
I originally messed up with loop breakers with it putting everything upside down and when I fixed it it is simply asking for an input and not doing anything else.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int height;
    int space;
    int rows;
    int hashes;

    // The code below decides if the users input meets the guide lines
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the heigth of the pyramid here");
        height = GetInt();
    }
    while (height <= 0 || height > 23);

    for(rows = 1 ;rows > height ;rows++)
    {
        // the code  gives the number of spaces per row
        for(space = height - 1;space >= 1;space--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        };

        //The code below gives the number of hashes that have to be printed                                    
        for(hashes = height + 1 - space; hashes> 0; hashes--)
        {
            printf("#");
        };

        height =  height + 1
        printf("\n");                  
    }
};
```

Comment: Try fushall() to clear the console in buffer.

Comment: `rows > height` is mistake.

Comment: probably, should be `rows <= height` , `space = height - rows`, `hashes = rows + 1 - space` , and delete `height =  height + 1`

Comment: Use a debugger, set breakpoints, single step through your code, watch variables ..

Comment: Is it only me asking what GetInt(); Is about? this isn't part of the standard, is it?

Comment: Looking at it a second time, this is not the code you're running. There's a semicolon missing near the end.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, `space--` in the for loop leads it to `0`.

Comment: Note that the semicolons after the loop bodies are not really wanted — they're simply empty statement unrelated to the loop except that they are after the loop.  That is, instead of `for (…){ … };` you should omit that semicolon.  Also, the empty declaration after `main()` is not wanted; omit that trailing semicolon too.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is not going to iterate for a single time if `height` is not less than `1`.

```
for(rows = 1 ;rows > height ;rows++)
{
    //....
```

I modified your code like the following for `height = 5`

```
for (rows = 1; rows <= height; rows++) {// iterate up to height times 
    for (space = height - rows; space >= 1; space--) { // at first print spaces height -1 times. then spaces will be reduced by 1 from previous.
        printf(" ");
    };
    // at first print hashes 2 times. then hashes will be increased by 1 from previous.
    for (hashes = rows + 1; hashes > 0; hashes--) {
        printf("#");
    };
    printf("\n");
}
```

and get output:

```
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```